# Can we create multiple ActionResults in Sitecore SXA custom controller rendering?

Tags: sxa, presentation, controller

Per Sitecore SXA documentation, in SXA custom controller, we have to override the GetModel() method and we call repository to get the model. I would like to create multiple Action Results in Sitecore SXA custom controller rendering.  Can someone help me how to write multiple Action methods in a controller?

Comment: That doesn't sound like you are using SXA right. Why not use a Page List component with an item query listing the employees? Or a Search Result component with a scope query to filter employees?

Comment: Agree with Michael's comment.  How are you trying to represent this on a page - is the html totally unique or could you make use of or clone an existing SXA component.

Comment: @MichaelWest@Jen - I just gave some sample Action Results names. I have to call a third party service/db and then populate some Sitecore fields.